# Problem involving decomposition of measures

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $\mu$ be a signed measure. We wish to prove that $$\left| \int{f} \> d\mu \right| \leq \int{|f|} \> d|\mu|.$$

(We are given the following defintion: $\int{f} \> d\mu = \int{f} \> d\mu^{+} - \int{f} \> d\mu^{-}$.)

For the proof, I want to just write $$\left| \int{f} \> d\mu \right| = \left| \int{f} \> d\mu^{+} - \int{f} \> d\mu^{-} \right| \leq \left| \int{f} \> d\mu^{+} \right| + \left| \int{f} \> d\mu^{-} \right| \leq \int{|f|} \> d\mu^{+} + \int{|f|} \> d\mu^{-} = \int{|f|} \> d|\mu|.$$

But, I feel as though I am missing justification for the last (and, obviously, most important) equality. That is, I'm sure if that follows from the definition provided to me. Any help would be great!

Comment: I cannot find any mistake or lack.

Comment: The last equality is a direct application of the definition you recall.

Comment: For the last step, you use $|\mu| = \mu^+ + \mu^-$, where we have $\mu = \mu^+ - \mu^-$ and $\mu^+ \bot \mu^-$ is the Jordan decomposition of $\mu$. You could mention that. If you don't already know this (maybe this is your definition of $|\mu|$?), you should also prove it :)

Answer (score 0):

The last equality rests on the fact that $$|\mu|=\mu^++\mu^-,\tag{1} $$ where $\mu= \mu^+-\mu^-$ (Jordan-Hahn decomposition), where $\mu^+$ and $\mu^-$ are positive and muutually singular.

Equality (1) is either the definition of $|\mu|$, or it canbe deduced from the definition of $|\mu|$ with partitions using the supports of $\mu^+$ and $\mu^-$.